# Is same process subscription not possible in Rebus

Tags: servicebus, rebus

I am trying to use Rebus as internal bus within the same process/AppDomain.

I have modified the [Pub/Sub sample](https://github.com/mookid8000/Rebus/tree/master/samples/Rebus.Samples/PubSub.Publisher) and added a SameProcessHandler:

```
class SameProcessHandler : IHandleMessages<string>
{
    public void Handle(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Same Process: {0}", message);
    }
}
```

Added the subscription after the bus start:

```
Configure.With(adapter)
  .Logging(l => l.ColoredConsole(minLevel: LogLevel.Warn))
  .Transport(t => t.UseMsmqAndGetInputQueueNameFromAppConfig())
  .Subscriptions(s => s.StoreInXmlFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "rebus_subscriptions.xml")))
  .CreateBus()
  .Start();

adapter.Bus.Subscribe<string>();
```

Finally added the destination queue (not sure it is needed):

```
<rebus inputQueue="pubsubsample.publisher.input" 
  errorQueue="pubsubsample.publisher.error" 
  workers="1" maxRetries="5">
  <endpoints>
    <!-- brute force ownership - all core .NET types are owned by our publisher :) -->
    <add messages="mscorlib" endpoint="pubsubsample.publisher.input"/>
  </endpoints>
</rebus>
```

But I getting error "Rebus is currently not configured with an endpoint mapping mechanism" and I should either specify a destination at subscription time or change the config. I rather use the config, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need to specify that Rebus can look up endpoint mapping a.k.a. message ownership in your app.config:

```
.MessageOwnership(o => o.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
```

Actually, I think the error message explains this, and if I remember correctly, it even provides the necessary C# and XML that can resolve the situation ;)

Comment: Thanks... I was ... blind :)